# Map ElasticSearch LowLevelRestClient's Response to Bean

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic **LowLevelRestClient** to interact with my elastic instance, when I query the elastic using my search query it returns the response which is wrapped as an HttpEntity.

As per documentation of [Elastic Reading Responses](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-low-usage-responses.html) EntityUtils class of Apache provides a way to convert this HttpEntity into String which gives me below response. I just want to map this response to an appropriate Object.

**My Code Snippet:**

```
Request request = new Request("GET", "/neeraj_party/_search");
request.setJsonEntity(searchQuery);
Response response = lowLevelClient.performRequest(request);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

**ResponseBody looks like this**

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 32.986195,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "neeraj_party",
        "_type": "party",
        "_id": "28588489",
        "_score": 32.986195,
        "_source": {
          "name": "MUST HK LTD",
          "city_nm": "郑州",
          "@timestamp": "2019-03-23T18:28:07.305Z",
          "type": "json",
          "legal_nm": "MUST HK Ltd",
          "gr_id": "28588489",
          "path": "/ssd/sdds",
          "address": "郑州",
          "state_province_cd": "180",
          "country_iso2_cd": "CN",
          "host": "neeraj.com",
          "postal_cd": "450000",
          "@version": "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My Question is simple

> Do ElasticSearch provide any such bean which can represent this response, or Should I create my own CustomBean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SearchResponse` Object to achieve this.

If you use the `search(SearchRequest)` method, It gives you back a `SearchResponse` object (including aggs).

Or you also could make the `SearchResponse` from that String using this method.

```
public static SearchResponse getSearchResponseFromJson(String jsonResponse){
        try {
            NamedXContentRegistry registry = new 
            NamedXContentRegistry(DashboardCuke.getDefaultNamedXContents());
            XContentParser parser = 
                JsonXContent.jsonXContent.createParser(registry, jsonResponse);
            return SearchResponse.fromXContent(parser);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception " + e);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("exception " + e);
        }
    return new SearchResponse();
}
```

I got this information from here: [ElasticSearch Forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-json-response-to-searchresponse-object/124394)

Comment: this works with some modification, I don't know what `DashboardCuke` is but when i pass empty ArrayList to `NamedXContentRegistry` constructor, this code works fine.